# Offsetting of ellipse marker in QGIS?

Tags: symbology, markers, qgis-2.2

I have a point layer, with angle(real), width(real) and height(real).

I want make a ellipse marker that take this values.
But how I can offset the marker to left border (see http://1drv.ms/1lErGUp) . I try but «anchor point» (Hleft or Hright) don't make it (Vup and Vdown is alright).

I try to make an expression in «data defined properties» - , something like :

> "width"/2 || ',0'

or

> "width"/2 || ',0.0'

etc.